# Python - JIRAerror hhtp 403 url captcha challenge

Tags: python, jira

Hi I am trying to connect to Jira python package JIRA
Here is command

```
j_url = 'https://myserver.com/jira'
JIRA(j_url, auth=(user, pass), max_retries=5)
```

I am getting the following error. I was not getting this error before. Only thing is changed, I did changed my password yesterday and it failed few times

```
JIRAError: JiraError HTTP 403 url: https://xxxxxxx/jira/rest/auth/1/session
    text: CAPTCHA_CHALLENGE; login-url=xxxxxx/jira/login.jsp
```

Any idea what could be possible issue here?

Comment: Have you tried solving the captcha in your browser? Once solved you should be able to log in from the API.

Answer (score 1):

It is solved now.
There is Current failed logins count in Jira profile. If it exceed certain threshold then API is failing. You need to get it reset by Admin